# Chat Ping Notifications seem to be missing from inbox

Tags: support, chat, notifications, global-inbox, ping

I was trying to get an unread notification on my [spare account](https://meta.stackexchange.com) for some screenshots. I am logged into the network, and was on recently enough to @ autocomplete

I've tried [pinging](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9568309#9568309), [superpinging](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9568310#9568310), and other users pinging the account. When I joined the chat, I see the usual bubble notifications

[image: "4" bubble on profile picture in chat]

I'm wondering if I'm missing something or just hit upon a *weird* bug.

Seems a bit risky to miss *superpings*, as it's a useful moderation tool especially.

Comment: Pings, like all moderation features, are on strike. :-) Also, there's usually a delay before chat notifications reach the inbox. What are your bot account's settings for that?

Comment: ..... I embarassingly don't remember if I set instant notifications on this, or where its supposed to be set. I got em now, there's a delay and I know EXACTLY what's the issue  now

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Cody Gray - it turns out I'd literally forgotten about the existence of quicker notifications, and since I generally used this account to test things interactively (despite the name) as a non moderator user, I'd never noticed till now.

You can turn it on in your profile  - click on your avatar in chat, and go to user profile, click on preferences and make sure the checkbox is ticked

Comment: I said you the same in other expression earlier ;)