# View chat mentions across Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, chat, ping

Is it possible to view chat mentions across Stack Exchange sites?

Sometimes I'm doing something and I hear that sound that means somebody replied to me and it's in some tab of some window, where I have some Stack Exchange chat open. It might be *[Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)*, *[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour)* or something, some room somewhere...   I think it means somebody replied to me. I might be in another window and not not see the speaker symbol flash for a moment in the chrome tab.

A solution would be if I could view all replies to me.

Is there a way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What events trigger an inbox notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319353/what-events-trigger-an-inbox-notification). "Unlike other notifications, which are instantaneous, this usually has a delay of 15 minutes. However, you can opt in your chat profile to receive notifications more quickly, in which case there won't be a delay." See also [Chat Ping Notifications seem to be missing from inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390956/)

Comment: Sorry, I'd not read the question properly when I answered.

Comment: @bobble Not a duplicate of that question. That post is about main site notifications, and so it doesn't address this question. Chat pings aren't shown there unless they resulted in a site notification (not dismissed within 15 minutes unless the immediate notification preference is selected in one's chat profile settings).

Comment: @Sonic but it does have "chat" section so I've added the tag. Still not duplicate though, because there is another way to see the pings, I'll post answer about it soon.

Comment: @bobble To be more specific, this question is asking if there's a way to view all of a user's chat mentions, even if they didn't result in site notifications. Note that the next bullet after the one you quote also says there won't be a notification if the user has dismissed the mention within 15 minutes either manually or by posting a message in the same room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way without depending on notifications which bobble mentioned in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395497/view-chat-mentions-across-stackexchange-sites#comment1322949_395497), is to leave a browser tab open with one room, then you can see pings from any other chat room on the same chat domain.

This comes in two forms:

1. When you get a ping in a room you're currently in, you will see this in the right sidebar of any other room you are in as well:

   [image: ping display in the chat room right sidebar]
2. When you get a ping in a room you're not currently inside, you will get a banner message on top of any other chat room you're in:

   [image: banner message saying you have been mentioned in other chat room]

Both of these stay until you dismiss them, so no risk of not seeing them like the browser's speaker icon.

Comment: i'm not seeing it https://i.imgur.com/8vt7qAH.png

Comment: @barlop because the ping is in the same room, in that case you see it in the room itself, there is a number on your avatar in the bottom left on the screen. My answer is for the case you get pings in other rooms, i.e. way to see pings across all sites/rooms as you requested.

Comment: so in this little greyed out area that is hardly noticable 'cos it's so greyed out?  https://i.imgur.com/6Rirt1s.png  ?

Comment: @barlop it's grayed out because there was no activity, but when there is activity it does get a color, and when you get a ping, a number with red circle appears, which is easy to notice. See the screenshot in the answer.

Comment: what do you mean "there was no activity"? What is "activity"?  isn't somebody in a chat replying to me, "activity"?

Comment: also there is a reply to me here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147847/web-apps-se-moderation-discussion    That does show in the greyed out area of a chat room,  but does not show under the expanding thing with number in red circle   https://i.imgur.com/yZxEyx3.png

Comment: @barlop oh, I see the source of the confusion. You want list of all **past** mentions, sadly such thing does not exist. What I talk about all the time is only the active pings, when you clear the ping, it's lost and you can't see it anywhere anymore. Writing a message in the chat clears the ping as well.

Comment: What do you mean by  "a ping"?  I can see past comments that are replies to me, one could call them "pings"  they still show in the red circle thing. Do you mean only chat replies to me that won't show after there is talk after them?

Comment: @barlop this here is also a ping, triggered by a comment reply. In chat ping can be triggered as well, but unlike comment won't become a notification in your inbox right away so yes if you clear it either manually or by posting a new message, it won't become a notification and be "lost".

Comment: You write "this here is also a ping, triggered by a comment reply. In chat ping can be triggered as well, "  <-- I don't even understand the English of that.  Do you mean a ping is a reply, whether that reply is a comment, or whether the reply is to a chat message?  But my question is only about chat replies not about "pings" in general. When you write "ping"  or "mention", I can't tell when you are talking about chat replies or comment replies or both. More specific language would be clearer.

Comment: @barlop yeah, guess it was somewhat obscure. What I meant is that the comment here triggers inbox notification. Such notification can also be triggered by a chat reply, but only if you don't dismiss the chat ping either by clicking the number with red circle, or just writing something.

Comment: Well I don't necessarily need "inbox notification" in the sense of a red circle. Just it being in the inbox.  I just tried typing in a dot in here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access   https://i.imgur.com/ZWan2Rt.png   And if I look at my inbox, it still shows that chat reply from OakBot https://i.imgur.com/hQdo5fB.png  Are all chat replies to me going to be in my inbox?

Comment: Also, here is a chat reply to me https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147847/web-apps-se-moderation-discussion  pic here https://i.imgur.com/rVIDBHv.png  And I don't see it in my inbox even looking https://stackexchange.com/users/163640/barlop?tab=inbox  first page shows from Dec 12th till today Dec 19th and it's not there.  (Yet the chat reply from oakbot shows!)

Comment: see my inbox here https://i.imgur.com/dgcqqHb.png The only chat reply showing for Sat  16th is from OakBot which was in the root chat room on superuser,    It's not showing the one from the arcade stackexchange site chat room discussing webapps https://i.imgur.com/rVIDBHv.png from galactic.

Comment: any idea why?,, ta

Comment: You probably cleared the ping from galacticninja that's why it didn't reach your inbox. Try to enable "Quicker notifications" by going to your chat profile, there go to the "prefs" tab and you will see checkbox labelled "Quicker notifications". Tick it, and the pings you get in chat will turn into inbox notifications quickly. (I don't know how quick though.)

Comment: Well that image of my inbox is from the "Go to full inbox" link. In the full inbox page, Would that listing of a reply from "Oakbot" on Dec 16th disappear if I reply to it?   Regarding any choice of "quicker notifications", I don't think speed of notifications(quick or not), has been an issue here.